# is it possible to set the dockerfile run command log level

Tags: docker, logging

when using docker to build the image, I want the log level to be warning, only output the warning/error log, ignore the info level. is it possible to do like that? I am searching from internet and only found the command like this:

```
RUN command > /dev/null 2>&1
```

this totally disable the log output. how to keep the error log.

Comment: Are you referring to your app logs or the workflow run logs? If it's your app logs, then you must be able to control its logging levels.